# How to use pyserial with a device connected with a USB port?

Tags: python, pyserial

I am currently trying to use pyserial to read the values from my handheld tachometer, the specific model is the DT-2100.
I am using python 3 and my current code looks like this:

```
# Imports
import serial

import time
import io

# Coding section

# Setting Parameters
port = "COM3"
baud = 38400
data = []
info = 0

# Setting the port location, baudrate, and timeout value
ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=2)

# Ensuring that the port is open
if ser.isOpen():
    print(ser.name + ' is open...')

# trying to read a single value from the display
#input("Ensure that the DT-2100 is turned on...")

info = ser.write(b'CSD')
ser.write(b'CSD')
info_real = ser.readlines()
print()
print("The current value on the screen is: ", info)
print()
print("The real value on the screen is: ", info_real)
```

This is what I get back after running the code:

```
COM3 is open...

The current value on the screen is:  3

The real value on the screen is:  []

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The main issue is that I should be getting the value that is displayed by the tachometer, which for this test was 0, but between my two attempted methods I got 3 and nothing.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know anything about the tachometer, but why do you have `ser.write(b'CSD')` twice in your code?

Comment: I did that because I was not quite sure how to properly get that information sent to the device, and they seemed to give me different responses.

Comment: I suggest you consult the documentation to find out which commands you need and the exact responses expected. Sending the same command twice is almost never the answer.

Comment: I have, the command I am trying to send is the CSD that I have there, and the expected response in that instance was a 0. However, I did not seem to get a response from the device.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of the `CSD`? Could it be: `CSD\n`?

Comment: https://www.checkline.com/res/products/200059/DT-2100commandset.zip

Comment: This is the command list provided by the website for the device

Answer (score 1):

The zip file you linked to contained an xls file which seemed to detail all the commands.

All the commands seem to be wrapped in: `<STX> cmd <CR>`, so you are missing those.

The `CSD` command would need to be like this: `ser.write(b'\x02CSD\r')`

Similarly the reply is also wrapped in the same way and you would need to remove those bytes and interpret the rest.

Comment: This worked, thank you for helping! Do you have any recommendations on ways to remove the added bytes from the reply?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask a new question about that. You should be able to show the bytes from the response. There will be two parts, I imagine: 1. Remove the wrappings 2. Interpret the remaining packet.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out how to remove the bytes and just get the necessary information. Also, I tried to upvote you, but I do not have enough reputation to cast a vote. Sorry.